# How to change the font style,family and size?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I Got a Problem Here
i have a lable in my IB Named Demo_Lable
now i wanated to change The Font Family,size,Paddings of the Demo_Lable with the fallowing Attributes

```
        padding-left:7px; 
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        color: #215968;
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family:Tahoma,Verdana;
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you need to be more specific .

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `UILabel` documentation? Have you looked at the attributes for `UILabel` in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Use @interface NSMutableAttributedString : NSAttributedString

- (void)setAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs range:(NSRange)range;

Answer (score 1):

```
self.yourLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
self.yourLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Also you can change font type like this : `[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14]`

You can use this codes